# Funny HTML behavior in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<li>
    <div id="some_id_1">-some html-</div>
</li>
```

The `<li>` has an image as a background, and the `<div>` appears as a control box on the top-right corner of the `<li>`.

The `<div>` is floated right, and should show up on the right.

When I refresh the page (in Chrome), the `<div>` shows up close to the middle of the `<li>` (as shown in the image on the left).

When I open Chrome's developer tools, and change the opacity (or any other css property) of the `<div>`, it shifts to the right (as shown in the image on the right).

I tried clearing Chrome's cache, but it didn't work.

Any Chrome-specific issues that might be causing this? (The page works fine in Firefox.)

[image]
[image: Screenshot]

CSS:

```
li {
 position:relative;
}
div {
 position:absolute;
 width:40px;
 float:right;
 margin:0px;
}
```

(all other properties relate to fonts/colors)

Update: margin-right:0px seems to have fixed problem, but I'm still confused why changing the opacity moved the div around.

Comment: Add your entire code (CSS & HMTL) ...

Comment: Or a fiddle? Creating the fiddle will also help you focus on what is the underlying issue.

Comment: Just by curiosity, have you tried doing a position:absolute;right:0 instead of float:right?

Comment: right:0 works, but since the layout is responsive, resizing the browser window increases the width of the li, and the <div> moves outside the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `margin-right:0px;`

if you are using `float:right;` try: `clear:both;`
what is your css? hard to help you this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `position:absolute` to place the div then make sure li has `position:relative`

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;

}
div{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:40px;
    background:#333; 
    color:white;
    border-radius:4px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GG2Da/4/)**

Comment: The positions of the <li> and the <div> are relative and absolute, respectively. I was just wondering why changing the opacity would affect the position of the element.